# How to add company name to return/back address in scrlttr2?

Tags: koma-script, scrlttr2

I have taken the simple example from the KOMA script guide from page 166-167 [(pdf)](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf). I now wish to introduce a company name in the line before (or after) my name. I would naively do so by changing

```
\setkomavar{fromname}{John Public}
```

to

```
\setkomavar{fromname}{Company Name\\John Public}
```

However, this breaks compilation. The error message is

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\@gnewline ...\@nolnerr \else \unskip \reserved@e 
                                                  {\reserved@f #1}\nobreak \...
l.24 \closing{Expecting an invitation}
```

Consequently, removing the `\closing{}` command correctly renders the document, but, obviously, without a closing. Note, that I am not actually concerned about the closing, I just want it to work as usual.

### Questions:

- How do I properly add a company name to the `from` variables, i.e., the return address?
- What causes this weird error?

### Full example:

```
\documentclass[foldmarks=true,foldmarks=blmtP,
fromalign=false,fromrule=afteraddress,
fromphone,fromemail,
version=last]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}
%\setkomavar{fromname}{John Public}
\setkomavar{fromname}{Company Name\\John Public}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Valley 2\\
54321 Public-Village}
\setkomavar{fromphone}{0\,12\,34~56\,78}
\setkomavar{fromemail}{Peter@Public.invalid}
\begin{letter}{%
Joana Public\\
Hillside 1\\
12345 Public-City%
}
\opening{Dear chairman,}
the last general meeting was about one year ago.
I want to remind you, that the constitution of our
club advises you to make a general meeting every
six month. Because of this I expect the executive
board to detain such a meeting immediately.
\closing{Expecting an invitation}
\ps PS: I hope you accept this as an friendly
demand note.
\setkomavar*{enclseparator}{Enclosure}
\encl{Compendium of the constitution with the
general meeting paragraphs.}
\cc{executive board\\all members}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\setkomavar{signature}{Company Name\\john Public}`

Comment: You can keep the name that makes trouble now (including the company name) and just add the above comment later. Seems to be a bug.

Comment: I found a new solution using `\linebreak`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**0. The hack**

The hack that (for the time being) may solve your problem, is using `\linebreak` instead of `\\`.

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\begin{document}
\setkomavar{fromname}{Company Name\linebreak\ John Public} % \_ before name typeset
%                                                               the `back address`
%                                                               correctly.
\begin{letter}{empfaenger}
    \opening{Hallo}
    text
    \closing{schluss}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

(Works for me; your mileage may vary!)

**1. Company name in signature**

To add the company name in the signature, you may try to redefine the KOMA-variable `signature`. Here is how I have set up my system:

In a general company .LCO

```
\newkomavar{companyname}
\setkomavar{companyname}{Incognito Ltd}

\setkomavar{fromname}{Nomen Nescio}
\setkomavar{signature}{\usekomavar{fromname}\\%
                       \footnotesize{\chairPerson}}



\providecaptionname{UKenglish}{\salutation}{Yours sincerely\linebreak\ Company Ltd.}
\providecaptionname{norsk}{\salutation}{Med vennlig hilsen\linebreak\ Company Ltd.}
```

In my personal .LCO

```
\setkomavar{fromname}{My Name}
\providecaptionname{UKenglish}{\chairPerson}{General Counsel/attorney at law \textsc{mna}}
\providecaptionname{norsk}{\chairPerson}{juridisk direkt\o r/advokat \textsc{mna}}
```

Using `\closing` gives me the desired output. I load the company .LCO and my personal .LCO in a template .tex-file. `\providecaptionname` gives you the possibility to use `babel` and multiple language. I use `\linebreak\` instead of `\\`, and

```
\renewcommand{\raggedsignature}{\raggedright}
```

**2. Company name in back address**

To have company name in back address line (see manual page 160 ff.):

```
\newkomavar{companyname}
\setkomavar{companyname}{Incognito Ltd}

\setkomavar{backaddress}{%
     \usekomavar{companyname}\\%
     \usekomavar{fromname}\\%
     \usekomavar{fromaddress}%    % remember to define this
  } 
\setkomavar{backaddressseparator}{$\cdot$} % or a comma
```

**3. Company name in first page header**

You have to redefine `firsthead` to achieve this:

```
\setkomavar{firsthead}{%
      \centering\usekomavar{companyname}\\%
      \usekomavar{fromname}\\%
      \rule{12em}{0.75pt}\\%
      \usekomavar{fromaddress}%
  }
```

Comment: Very nice. Thanks also for explaining the possibility to use the same setup for different languages. However, your solution only adds the company name to the closing (which includes the signature variable). I would like the company name to also be in the return and back address displayed in the upper part of the letter. I edited the question title accordingly.

Comment: See edit, and the manual page 160 ff.

Comment: I have developed my .LCOs over several years, and they are messy. The main point is: Define variables with suitable names, and use those variables in the standard KOMA-variables (look at the illustration of a letterhead at page 158 in the manual). Variables in the KOMA-letter class are like LEGO bricks.

Comment: We're getting there. Now, could you also put it in the letterhead? I just want the company name to appear every time my name appears, as would properly expressed by `\setkomavar{fromname}{Company Name\\John Public}` if it worked.

Comment: @Jost I have been away from my computer, see my EDIT 2

Comment: I came up with the same solution. This somewhat defeats the purpose of the scrlttr macros, if I have to define everything by myself for such an easy question. This should totally be fixed. Anyway, thank you for your time and help!

Comment: @Jost I do not agree. `scrlttr2` has some sensible default and all the flexibility to build your own letterhead

Comment: Got a reply by the maintainer: Using \\ is `fromname` is undocumented. Dependent on where ariables are used, everything can happen. AFAIR, using \\ is only docuemented in `fromaddress`, `toaddress` and `backaddress` and not with the function of a line sep, but a field separator. \par Everybody in need of a company name, may define a new variable and also define its use, as is done for example in `asymTypB.lco`. http://www.komascript.de/node/1888#comment-4917

Comment: @Johannes_B `\newline` works, but you have to correct indentation if you are not using `\renewcommand{\raggedsignature}{\raggedright}`.

Comment: Defining a new variable, like you are showing in your answer are better, wouldn't even tell about `\newline` ;-) btw, tried `\newline` this afternoon. It messes other stuff up. So, not recommended :-p

Comment: @Johannes_B Thanks for asking Markus Kohm. Seems like I have tapped on quite a sensitive topic here.

Comment: @Jost Why sensitive topic? Think about it, one guy sitting on his desk thinking about what users might need. Users have all kinds of crazy ideas, and really creative ways of inputting stuff. In this case, the author maybe never thought that someone could do that.